# How to make the whole scene in dark on unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Likes that when the game is pause, only the Resume button is lighted, other whole scene is in dark, Is there some function can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a GUITexture object: in unity menu:  GameObject  ->  Create GUI Texture, let’s call it darkBackground;
- Attach a dark texture to darkBackground;
- Disable darkBackground object (you can do it interactively or programatically call)

  darkBackground.SetActive(false);

When paused, turn on /enable this GUITexture game object by calling

```
darkBackground.SetActive(true);
```

Comment: Or subsequently, you can create a UIPanel with a dark texture and get the same effect (Unity 4.6.x & Unity 5.x only)  :)

Comment: I am with you, Zze! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: What if I want some rectangular areas to be highlight? Must I write a shader?

Comment: You don't have to use shade, which I don't recommend. Simply resize the GUITexture or UIPanel will do.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your doing, The way I do it is:

- Create a second camera for the GUI.
- Set the second camera depth to be behind your main camera.
- Add a black colored plane in front of the GUI Camera (Pick the shader to be transparent)
- Add a script to this item so on pressing the GUI button it would activate it and set transparency to the level you want.

```html
      float transparency = 0f;
      bool isGUIAcitve = false;
  

      if(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.P) && this.isGUIActive == false){

        gameObject.GetComponent <Renderer>().enabled = true; 
        Color oldPlaneColor = GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color;
        oldPlaneColor.a = this.transparency;
        GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = oldPlaneColor;

        }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.P) && this.isGUIActive == true){

          gameObject.GetComponent <Renderer>().enabled = false;

        }
```

P.S: You can swap the plane for a GUITexture or a Spriter Renderer image.